# Enrich kafka stream from different topics using different keys

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

How can I join a stream with another topic with different keys?

All topics for all tables/streams below are  being sourced by DB tables using Kafka connect.

My app is a Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka written as a single consumer in a group, so that I can consume all partitions per topic.

I have a stream like this:

Stream S1 from topic S has 3 partitions:

> key: keyval|someval, val1: "keyval", val2: "someval"
> key: keyval|someval1, val1: "keyval", val2: "someval1"

and another topic like this

T1 w/ 6 partitions:

> key: tabval|keyval, val1: "tabval", val2: "keyval", val3: "someval"
> key: tabval1|keyval1, val1: "tabval1", val2: "keyval", val3: "someval"

here `tabval|keyval` is the key that's loaded based on them being foreign keys from 2 other tables on the actual db table we load this topic from.

I have tried using a `GlobalKTable` for reading T1 and do a `leftJoin()` with stream S1 but I cannot do that as S1 doesn't have the part of the key in T1 i.e `tabval`

Now if I try to key T1 using `keyval|someval` I will only get latest write on that key when I make T1 a `GlobalKtable` and consume, I guess this would happen even if I just use it as a `KTable`?

But I need all records from T1 that match `keyval|someval` combo from the topic S and not just the last update.
Should I consume T1 as a table then to a stream and then `rekey` and merge based on a `window()`?

I have to consume all partitions from both topics in this consumer so the lookup works and in the end I have all data from T1

How can I achieve this please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just giving you a gist of how join works in kakfa between different data abstraction (KStreame/KTable/GlobalKTable), that you need to understand before you implement the same.

### Join co-partitioning requirements.

- Input data must be co-partitioned when joining.
- This ensures that input records with the same key, from both sides of the join, are delivered to the same stream task during processing.
- It is the responsibility of the user to ensure data co-partitioning when joining.
- Consider using global tables (GlobalKTable) for joining because they do not require data co-partitioning.

### Why is data co-partitioning required?

- KStream-KStream, KTable-KTable, and KStream-KTable joins are performed based on the keys of records (e.g., leftRecord.key == rightRecord.key).
- It is required that the input streams/tables of a join are co-partitioned by key.
- KStream-GlobalKTable joins is exempted as co-partitioning is not required because all partitions of the GlobalKTable‘s underlying changelog stream are made available to each KafkaStreams instance, i.e. each instance has a full copy of the changelog stream. (Ref : https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/ce9be56c214914cc9b1342c32fd59c06141e500a/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/GlobalKTablesExample.java)
- A KeyValueMapper also allows for non-key based joins from the KStream to the GlobalKTable.

### Ensuring data co-partitioning

- If the inputs of a join are not co-partitioned yet, we must ensure it manually by following the below procedure.
- Identify the input KStream/KTable in the join whose underlying Kafka topic has the smaller number of partitions. Let’s call this stream/table “SMALLER”, and the other side of the join “LARGER”.
- Pre-create a new Kafka topic for “SMALLER” that has the same number of partitions as “LARGER”. Let’s call this new topic “repartitioned-topic-for-smaller”.
- Within your application, re-write the data of “SMALLER” into the new Kafka topic. You must ensure that, when writing the data with to or through, the same partitioner is used as for “LARGER”.

Once you understand these pre-requisites clearly, match with your requirement, whether it is valid, if yes, you can find appropriate samples from here https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/ce9be56c214914cc9b1342c32fd59c06141e500a/README.md (Just do search with 'join')

Comment: So I just have a single consumer so all partitions should be with my consumer anyway even for KTable. 

However If I use GlobalKTable how can I change the keys on it to match my stream as my stream to be joined doesn't have needed fields for GKTable to match ... and if I can change the keys on GKTable then I shouldn't lose the duplicate rows i.e the same key rows shouldn't udpate to latest value in the GlobalKTable? Is there a way to do it please thx.